# svn switch --relocate not persisting

Tags: svn

We have moved our subversion repository to a different server. I have run `svn swtich --relocate` to change my development workstation repository to the new location.

The problem is that it looks like it works as there is no error message reported. But when I check the location of the repository after the command it has not updated.

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be or how to troubleshoot the problem?

I am running on XP with a user that has local administrator rights.

Comment: Might I suggest `svn update`?

Comment: I have tried running 'svn update' after the relocate command but since it is pointing at the old location still which is not there it fails.

Comment: How did you check the location of the repository after issuing the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was running the following command.

```
svn switch --relocate svn://oldrepositry/trunk svn://newrepository/trunk
```

I found that running this command I was able to persist the relocation.

```
svn switch --relocate svn://oldrepositry svn://newrepository
```

I did not have the whole repository checked out, just trunk.

This article may shed some light on why the first command silently fails. It suggests the from url being longer than the 'Repository Root' (which you can find using 'svn info') can cause this issue.

http://archives.devshed.com/forums/development-94/new--svn-switch---relocate-silently-fails-1264627.html

Comment: Gotcha for those using svn+ssh protocol -- if you are used to using the format

svn+ssh://username@path/to/repository

it does NOT work (silent fail) with switch --relocate.

omit the username.